# ES6 Return array of array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I’m having some issues with returning an array with the values from valueSet which are divisible by two. My main issue here is the ES6 syntax involved, I’ve been unable to find online the best way to return this.

```
const valuesSet = [2, 4, 6, 8, true, false, "nine"]

const divisibleNumbers = (array) => {

}
```

Right now I’m trying:

```
const valuesSet = [2, 4, 6, 8, true, false, "nine"]

var result = [];

const divisibleNumbers = (array) => {


    for (var x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        if (array[x] % 2) {
        result.push(array[x]);
        }
  }
  return result;

}

console.log (divisibleNumbers(valueSet));
```

But I'm getting the error message

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

and I'm unable to get my values to show in the console.

Comment: Use `"` to quote strings, not `“` or `”`.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, but for the record `if (array[x] % 2)` is not checking for even numbers. It `array[x] % 2` will return true for any number. `array[x] % 2 === 0` will check for even numbers. Again, not answering the question I know, but felt it necessary to point this out in case that's what you were trying to accomplish

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that

```
“nine”
```

is invalid syntax - string literal delimiters should always use *straight* quotes (or backticks, for template literals), not curly quotes. Use

```
"nine"
```

instead.

All you need is a simple `filter`:

```js
const valuesSet = [2, 4, 6, 8, true, false, "nine"]

const divisibleNumbers = array => array.filter(
  item => Number.isInteger(item) && item % 2 === 0
)
console.log(divisibleNumbers(valuesSet))
```

Comment: strangely, when i put brackets around array (eg. (array) => i get a syntax error. any idea of why that is? thanks

Comment: @CertainPerformance FYI, the word "brackets" has become the general term for all the different types of bracketing characters: `()`, `[]`, `{}`, and `<>`. To be specific about `[]` say "square brackets".

Comment: @Barmar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket Huh, you're right, for some reason I'd never heard parentheses included in the category before

Answer (score 0):

You could use filter to accomplish this easily.

```
const divisibleBy2 = valuesSet.filter(e => typeof e === 'number' && e % 2 == 0);
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the OPs problem: "*I'm getting the error message "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" and I'm unable to get my values to show in the console.*"

Comment: The OP has already reflected the fix for that in his question by replacing the curly quotation marks.